# How to get_queried_object on multiple objects?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, custom-post-type-archives

**My Setup**

I have a custom post type "zap_apartments" with 2 custom taxonomies "zap_audience" & "zap_cities".

I wrote some RewriteRules to access all "zap_apartments" for a "zap_audience" + "zap_cities" assigned. It is to filter the results with seo-friendly URLs:

it makes a request like `my-url.de/holiday/cologne/`
internally an url like `my-url.de/index.php?post_type=zap_apartments&zap_audience=holiday&zap_cities=cologne`

**My Problem**

When I try to access the taxonomy information on the custom archive page I only get 1 taxonomy returned:

```
print_r( get_queried_object() );
```

prints:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [term_id] => 17
    [name] => Cologne
    [slug] => cologne
    [term_group] => 0
    [term_taxonomy_id] => 17
    [taxonomy] => zap_cities
    [description] => 
    [parent] => 0
    [count] => 2
    [filter] => raw
)
```

Is there any way I can get the other assigned taxonomy "zap_audience" too?

I already asked google, but couldn't find anything useful. I also tried to access any value by `$_GET['zap_audience']` but it's empty.

Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it with `$_GET['zap_audience']`, but not quite, since it isn't passed in as a GET variable.

It is however a query variable, so try these:

```
$post_type = get_query_var( 'post_type' );
$audience  = get_query_var( 'zap_audience' );
$city      = get_query_var( 'zap_cities' );
```

Also +1 for prefixing your taxonomy types with `zap_`